# Cloudflare rule to add a trailing slash

Tags: url-rewriting, cloudflare

I'm moving between blogging engines and my new engine creates a very similar slug compared to the previous engine, it just adds a trailing slash (`/`) to the URL.

All my traffic is routed via Cloudflare, so I figured I should use Page Rules in order to get the forwarding to work.

What I came up with is the following:

```
https://my-website.com/* is forwarded with a 301 redirect to https://my-website.com/$1/
```

However, this creates the following (very logical) error:

> Forwarding URL matches the target and would cause a redirect loop

I can see why this is failing because the `*` matches everything. Is there some other notation I can use to forward to the proper pages?

I can't use IIS rewrites or `.htaccess`, as I'm using a static site hosting platform and don't have control over the webserver.

Comment: I have the exact same issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm sad to inform that I haven't. However, I noticed that 'somehow' my pages got resolved automatic, even withouth such a rule. So a link to `https://my-site/page` is showing the content of `https://my-site/page/`. I'm not sure if this is because of some CloudFlare, Azure CDN or Azure Blob Store feature. I do know it 'solved' my issue (for now).